# Display mysql data for Current Week in 7 day calendar

Tags: php, mysql

I need a guiding hand, how do I display the " current week" starting on Monday , in a 7-day calendar by a 7-room grid, for a small theatre I volunteer at, various voluntary town groups use the rooms.
My database name=rooms, table=roomdiary, it has 7 fields (field_1 to Field_7).

I can populate each day with data from the dbase using the "Select" query & php isset code where required.
But I am stumped on how to correctly display only " current week " data in the right room on right day.
>

```
////// Mon... Tues . Wed .. Thu .. Fri . Sat .. Sun
room 1 data . data . data . data . data  data . data
room 2 data . data . data . data . data  data . data
room 3 data . data . data . data . data  data . data
room 4 data . data . data . data . data  data . data
room 5 data . data . data . data . data  data . data
room 6 data . data . data . data . data  data . data
room 7 data . data . data . data . data  data . data
```

I apologise for having not posted any code, as I thought any generic advice would be more than helpful and help me learn. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you split this problem in two

1. Calculate start of display period (="Which date is the current Monday")
2. Select and display your records

The first point is quite easy using PHP's `date()` or `getdate()` functions, the second can be achieved by `SELECT ... WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN monday_date AND sunday_date`.

This helps modularize your program: What if you want to add future display options? What if your theater decides not to play on mondays?

Additionally I recommend against harcoding your 7 rooms into 7 fields: A relational approach would have a "rooms" table (currently with 7 rows) and a "performances" table linking a room and a date. If you add a "programs" table and also link it to the "performances" table, you already get the program data for free.

Comment: Very grateful Eugen Rieck, I will have a play around with the code and see where you guys helpful answers take me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Redesign Your database, make table rooms (room_id, room_name) and table schedule (room_id, date, data, week_nr, year)
2. Always write with date also week_nr to database - date('W', timestamp)
3. If you don't want to store week_nr in database, then try strtotime('Last monday', timestamp) and strtotime('Next sunday', timestamp) and select range from database dates

Comment: Many thanks Alvar FinSoft Soome, I need to digest your reply and try out some changes to my code.